# Input element with ngbTypeahead directive, does not update when formControlName value is modified programmatically

Tags: angular, typeahead, angular-reactive-forms, angular-bootstrap

In my app, I have an `input` element like the following

```
<input id="find-user"
                formControlName="userSearch"
                [resultTemplate]="rt"
                [ngbTypeahead]="userSearch">
```

I then have a button (just for testing) that calls a function

```
testAction() {
    (<FormGroup>this.userEntryForm.controls['userSearch'].setValue('Obama');
 }
```

This function successfully updates the form value (I can see when I inspect it), however it does not change the value inside the `input` field which is **supposed** to be bound to this form value.

Does anyone know why exactly this happens and how to work around it?
I can see that it is definitely related to the `ngbTypeahead` directive, since it works as expected when I remove this directive.

---

(if necessary, I can recreate this in a Plunkr, but hopefully someone can provide a solution without one)

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcd2qw?file=app%2Ftypeahead-basic.html. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet added some more options that I'm using but also couldn't reproduce it.. hmm I will continue investigating https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcd2qw-1e3adm?file=app%2Ftypeahead-basic.html